# How do I make sure that the canvas doesn't look blurry at HDPI screens?

Tags: dart

If I use the html canvas, everything looks blurry at HDPI screens. How can I fix this (using dart) ?

Answer (score 1):

You basicly need to make the canvas 2 times as big, and then rescale afterwards. Run some function like this before you draw anything to the canvas:

```dart
void fixHDPI() {
  num ratio = window.devicePixelRatio;
  if (ratio != 1) {
    num oldWidth = myCanvas.width, oldHeight = myCanvas.height;
    myCanvas
      ..width = (oldWidth * ratio).round()
      ..height = (oldHeight * ratio).round()
      ..style.width = "${oldWidth}px"
      ..style.height = "${oldHeight}px"
      ..context2D.scale(ratio, ratio);
  }
}
```

**[dartpad demo](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/b64da074618c4cd6afe7)**